# Difference between tf.nn.convolution and tf.nn.conv2d

Tags: tensorflow

Could someone explain me the difference between `tf.nn.convolution` and `tf.nn.conv2d` ?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.nn.conv2d` computes a **2-D** convolution given 4-D input and filter tensors, while `tf.nn.convolution` computes sums of **N-D** convolutions. Both return a `Tensor` with same type of input.

See [tt.nn.convolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution) and [tt.nn.con2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) for further understanding.